# What does MacOS actually do when open a file?

Tags: macos, file

**Background of this question:**

I built an application by LabVIEW to open .tdms file, and I know it can receive arguments that pass to it because following code works just fine:

```
open -a /Application/My.app --args /path/to/file.tdms
```

Since command line works, I decided to associate .tdms to my application so that I can double click the file to open it, and I succeed by modifying `My.app/Contents/info.plist`.

And things get interesting, when I try to open file either by double-click or choose app in "Open With..." list, a pop-up window shows

> "My.app" is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

Some suggested `xattr -cr /Application/My.app` would solve the problem, but it doesn't work for me.

**That's why I want to know what does macOS actually do in the background when open file? How does the arguments pass to application?**

---

*Additional info:*

1. *I use "Open Application Reference" and Property Node in LabVIEW to receive arguments that pass to my application.*
2. *I added following code into `info.plist` to associate filetype to my app:*

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>tdms</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>National Instruments TDMS File</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>icon.icns</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## LaunchServices

macOS includes [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services). This code is responsible for launching applications and providing those applications with the details of files to open or print:

> Launch Services is an API that enables a running application to open other applications or their document files or URLs (uniform resource locators) in a way similar to the Finder or the Dock. Using Launch Services, an application can perform such tasks as:
>
> - Open (launch or activate) another application
> - Open a document or a URL in another application
> - Identify the preferred application for opening a given document or URL
> - Register information about the kinds of document files and URLs an application is capable of opening
> - Obtain appropriate information for displaying a file or URL on the screen, such as its icon, display name, and kind string
> - Maintain and update the contents of the Recent Items menu

### AEOpenDocuments

To open files, graphical applications on macOS are sent AppleEvents of type [`odoc`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1527223-event_id_constants/kaeopendocuments):

> Event that provides an application with a list of documents to open. Sent, for example, when a selects one or more documents for your application in the Finder and double-clicks them.

The launched application's arguments do not include the paths of the files to open.

Comment: Thanks Graham, your answer do solve my confusions, guess I have to learn how to build app via xcode... I am totally new to xcode. Besides, do you know where can I find example codes regarding how to use "AEOpenDocuments"? I tried to google it but no luck...

Comment: Helpfully `NSDocumentController` and `NSDocument` handle the AppleEvent for modern applications; see [Developing a Document-Based App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_files_and_icloud/developing_a_document-based_app). Good luck!